# F# RProvider - Method not found RProvider.RInterop.call

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

I am trying (for the first time) to use RProvider from F# but I must be missing something since I can't get it to work. I get the following error message:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'RDotNet.SymbolicExpression RProvider.RInterop.call(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Object[], System.Object[])'.
>      at .$FSI_0020.main@()

Here is my code:

```
#r "../packages/R.NET.1.5.5/lib/net40/RDotNet.dll"
#r "../packages/RDOTNET.FSharp.0.1.2.1/lib/net40/RDotNet.FSharp.dll"
#r "../packages/RProvider.1.1.15/lib/net40/RProvider.dll"
#r "../packages/RProvider.1.1.15/lib/net40/RProvider.Runtime.dll"
#r "../packages/RProvider.1.1.15/lib/net40/RProvider.DesignTime.dll"
#r "../packages/DynamicInterop.0.7.4/lib/net40/DynamicInterop.dll"

open System
open RDotNet
open RProvider
open RProvider.``base``
open RProvider.graphics

R.mean(x=[1;2;3])
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Can you try referencing RProvider using the FsLab package? See www.fslab.org/download. It makes it easier to get compatible versions of everything and you'll need just a single `#load` to get all the references...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the quick reply. I tried it but now I get a different error message: ..packages\FsLab.0.3.11\FsLab.fsx(64,13): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Print' is not defined

Comment: When I comment out the appropriate lines is FsLab.fsx I get the same error as before

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I created a new solution and installed ONLY FsLab and once I did that it worked like charm. Thanks Tomas!

Comment: Great, glad to hear that this unblocked you! I would still be curious why you were getting the error - can you share your non-working solution somewhere?

Comment: My solution contains many projects. I'll try to create a minimal solution that demonstrates that, but it might take me some time. Thank you so much for the great assistance!